# first java program. confused on a error

Tags: java

i am confused about my program. The game is the wheel of fortune. When i run the program it works and adds the letters when guessed correct and does not add letters if not correct; although my program is showing 2 possible wins for my score, but i want it to only show one; also it adds to the score even if it is incorrect. any ideas would be helpful. thank you.

here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
* This is the main game which will call the coding that will implement the classes word       board and wheel in to a fully function game.
* @author 100206667
*
*/


public class WheelOfFortune {
public static int Score;
/**
* 
* @param args - This will loop through the code block underneath to allow the game to work. */

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Wheel w = new Wheel();
        WordBoard b = new WordBoard();
        int usrGuess = -1;
        String feedback = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean match;
        char guess;
        int score;

     // Main game loop
        do {
            if (w.spin().length() > 4) {
                // Free spins, bankrups....still need to be added
            } else {
            Score = Score + Integer.valueOf(w.spin().toString());
            }
            System.out.println("Your score is " + Score);     

            //The error is here in my program. (i know that much)

            String segment = w.spin();

            System.out.println( b.getHiddenPhrase() );

            System.out.println("Make a guess:");

            String input = sc.nextLine();
            guess = input.charAt(0);

            match = b.checking(guess);

             // missing feedback

            System.out.println(feedback);

        }while ( !b.finshGame() );

        sc.close();

     // Display feedback

        if (usrGuess != -1){

           // is not displaying when game finishes.
                System.out.println("Well done. Your final score is");

        } else System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
     }
}
```

would appreciate the help. thank you.

Comment: [SSCCE: learn it, know it, love it](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: sorry i am bad at explaining things

Comment: Try showing some sample input/output to demonstrate the problem.  If it's easily demonstrated its usually easily solved - this is not clear.

Comment: it seems easier to ignore or flag a question you find problematic than to post nonconstructive comments. Try offering tips on how to ask better questions, don't just troll someone - not everyone is as experienced as you

Answer (score 1):

I can't really attest to the correctness of the score as the value is coming from the Wheel object added to the score.
 I did a mock up of your code and the logic here is fine, minus anything you're pulling from other objects - the do..while will terminate and only print once.
 you have `System.out.println("Well done. Your final score is");` but there is no variable being printed afterward and the `score` print occurs once every time the loop is executed.
 `if (usrGuess != -1){` and the arguments afterward will never display because you have `usrGuess` hardcoded to be -1 and it isn't being modified anywhere locally.
 You should just remove that the condition altogether - once the while loop terminates it will execute the next line of code.
 The logic for letter adding isn't possible to debug for you - you should post your other classes along with this